# URL in loop php, request uri

Tags: php, loops, request-uri

I have a php code:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/?task=entry.add&sid=67'){echo'<script type="text/javascript">window.location.assign("/index.php");</script>';}else{echo"";}
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/?task=entry.add&sid=68'){echo'<script type="text/javascript">window.location.assign("/index.php");</script>';}else{echo"";}
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/?task=entry.add&sid=69'){echo'<script type="text/javascript">window.location.assign("/index.php");</script>';}else{echo"";}
```

and I'm trying to do this in loop (ids should be for example from 67 to 100)

```
<?php
  $page = $_POST['id'];
  for ($i=1; $i<=$id; $i++){
    $url = "/?task=entry.add&sid=".$i."<br/>";
    echo'<script type="text/javascript">window.location.assign("/index.php");</script>';}else{echo"";
  }
?>
```

what should i do more, and where is my problem?

Comment: what errors you get? or what doesn't work properly?

Comment: you've really got to expand, it isn't very clear.

Comment: You assign `$page` but then use `$url`? There's an `$id` in there too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you forgot to add your `if` statement.

```
<?php
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    for ($i=1; $i<=$id; $i++)
    {
        $url = "/?task=entry.add&sid=".$i;

        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == $url)
        {
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location.assign("/index.php");</script>';
        }
        else
        {
            echo"";
        }
    }
?>
```

Here is a correction.

- I added the if
- fixed few `;` missing

Comment: thanks :) i had to delete first line and change $id to for example 500 because i know how many ids i have :)

Answer (score 0):

i think you need like this:

If you have range  of id then you can smiply do that:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['id']) && $_REQUEST['id'] >66 && $_REQUEST['id'] <= 100) {
 echo'<script type="text/javascript">window.location.assign("/index.php");</script>'
}
else {
  echo "";
}
```

if you have random ids then you can do like this:

make array of ids :

```
$arrIds = array(67,68,69,.....,100);
```

then simply check like that if current id in this array:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['id']) && in_array($_REQUEST['id'],$arrIds)){
 echo'<script type="text/javascript">window.location.assign("/index.php");</script>'

}
else {
  echo "";

}
```

it will check if current id is in the array then it will echo script . it will not need any loop. It should makes sense.

Comment: Not if they have to do this lots of times!

Comment: but i need this to do in a loop because it would be to many cases (ids)

Comment: @user3045185: did you try this?